# .NET3.5 SP1 patch

Tags: .net-3.5

Is the .NET3.5 SP1 patch cummulative? Means if I roll out .NET3.5 SP1, will it include or support .NET1.1 and 2.0 as well, or do I have to release all three versions in a order??

Thanks

Comment: I believe 3.5 only supports 2.0 and 3.0, but not 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.net 3.5 SP1 uses .net framework 2.0 and 3.0, so they are included when you install 3.5SP1

.net 1.1 is a separate install: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=262D25E3-F589-4842-8157-034D1E7CF3A3&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

V3.5sp1 supports V2.0, V3.0 and V3.5, as I believe they all built upon V2.0 CLR.

It will not, however, install V1.1 as this is an entity in it's own right.

Answer (score 1):

I installed .NET 3.5 SP1 in a VM and was able to run a .NET application targeting .NET 2.0 just fine.